# I can't remove Visual Stduio Ultimate 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I want to install Visual Stduio 2013(update 4), and I have a  Visual Stduio 2013(update 5) in my computer. When I was going to install update 4, the notice said I have an upper edition and stopped my installtion. I tried to remove it in my control panel and it didn't work. Then I use a knit called "WINDOWS INSTALLER CLEAN UP", it didn't work either. What's more, I have searched all the files and applications, I can't find Visual Stduio 2013(update 4) in my computer.[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Comment: @LexLi I have tried it.The Visual Studio Unistaller Application cannot remove Visual Studio completely.